# MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlwWZ.png)

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: 
org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject, 
at table: options, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(option)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    ... 108 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type for the JSONObject. Check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) for more details.

Another working example is [this one](https://github.com/radogost/hibernate-mysql-json).

[image: this is how entity definition should look like]